# Optimizing code in Objective-C for searching through arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, optimization

I am working on an iOS app that will load points (MKAnnotationView's) onto a map (MKMapView), but only if a category that the location is in is enabled (so the user can turn points on and off).

I am pulling the points from a database using JSON, and read the objects into 3 arrays: locs is an array of locations (name, ID, coordinate, description, image data), cats is an array of categories (name, ID, image data), and tags is a collection of category-location pairs (a category ID & a location ID).

To add the points to the map, I am using a couple loops that find which category a location is in, and then checks if that category is on the map. The problem is that this way of adding locations is taking a long time when it runs on a device (about 6-10 seconds on an iPhone 4S). I'm wondering if there is a good way to optimize this code that will speed everything up.

Here is my code as it stands now. This code runs whenever the mapview is loaded. Points is an array of all points that can be shown on the map, shownPoints is an array of all points with their categories enabled:

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:points];

for (searchLocation *tempLoc in locs ) 
{
    name = tempLoc.name;
    description = tempLoc.description;

    latiString = tempLoc.latiString;
    longiString = tempLoc.longiString;

    coordinate.latitude = latiString.doubleValue;
    coordinate.longitude = longiString.doubleValue;

    imageData = tempLoc.picture;

    MapViewAnnotation *destinationPoint = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:name andCoordinate:coordinate andDescription:description andImageData:imageData];

    [points addObject:destinationPoint];

    for (CatTag *tempCatTag in tags) 
    {
        if ([tempCatTag.locationID isEqualToString: tempLoc.locID])
        {
            for (Category *tempCat in cats)
            {
                if ([tempCatTag.categoryID isEqualToString:tempCat.catID] && 
                    [[shownCategories objectAtIndex:[cats indexOfObject:tempCat]] isEqualToString: @"YES"])
                {
                    [shownPoints addObject: destinationPoint];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:shownPoints];
```

}

Comment: What type are `locationID`/`locID` and `categoryID`/`catID`?

Comment: `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempLoc.name] init]` is very wrong. Just use `tempLoc.name`. Same for `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", tempCat.catID]`.

Comment: Both the `locationID/locID` and `categoryID/catID` are NSStrings. The values are all numeric, so if converting them to ints will help, that's no problem.

Comment: Have you looked at predicates to filter the array?

Comment: What part of the code takes up the most time when profiling the application with Instruments?

Comment: @sch - I have around 100 locations, 150 tags (location/category pairs), and 10 categories. These numbers may change in the future, but should be pretty close to where they are now.

Comment: Maybe, instead of filtering through an array based on locID, you could store arrays of locations in an NSDictionary, key coded according to locID, and access it like so:  `shownPoints = [myLocationsDictionary objectForKey:tempLoc.locID];  [self.mapView addAnnotations:shownPoints];`

Comment: Can you explain better the content of the arrays and specially `tags`? Also, what can you explain what `points`, `shownPoints` and `shownPoints` are?

Comment: Better and optimized way of searching can be achieved by using `NSPredicate` Object, You can write your queries in cocoa. To know more about this [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) is the class reference and [Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) . Certainly they will be more helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a join on tags.categoryID == cats.catID using nested loops (N^2, maybe even N^3 since you have an objectAtIndex: in there).

What if you had:

```
NSDictionary *tagsByLocationId = ...
NSDictionary *catsByCategoryId = ...
```

The first one would have a key of locationID and a value being the set of all CatTags in tags that had that locationID.  Similarly for the catsByCategoryId.

Now you would:

```
for (CatTags *catTag in [tagsByLocationId objectForKey:tempLoc.locID]) {
    for (Category *cat in [catsByCategoryId objectForKey:catTag.categoryID]) {
        if ([shownCategories objectAtIndex:[cats indexOfObject:cat]]) {
            [shownPoints addObject:destinationPoint];
        }
    }
}
```

Some thoughts:

- the [shownCategories objectAtIndex:[cats indexOfObject:cat]] could be another lookup in an NSDictionary
- it may be that tagsByLocationId and catsByCategoryId would have a single value per key.  your code allows for multiple -- it scans them all and does not stop when it has a match.  if so, adjust the index (tagsByLocationId) to be a key -> single value

Either way this will reduce the solution to O(1) since you are doing two direct lookups in a hash table.  Should be a LOT faster.